# Using an AC rated light switch for switching DC logic level voltage

Tags: switches, ac, dc

Would it be safe and within electrical code to switch logic level DC voltage using a standard AC light switch? I know high power DC lines can create arcing with a switch of that style but low power should not.

Comment: Where are you?  What are you intending to build the switch into?  Not likely to cause a problem, but the legality of it can be tricky for construction or commercial devices.

Comment: I'm in the US. I realize that it works but I was wondering on the legality of it

Comment: If you're in the US, then you must meet or exceed all relevant standards for commercial devices and housing, but for a hobby device not part of your house, there should be little harm.  Note that current matters as well as voltage when interrupting a circuit, as well as inductance.  If you are building something into an insured building or device, use a device certified to switch the current and voltage and if you must use a device not marked with appropriate certification (UL, CSA etc), get an engineer to sign an exception order.

Comment: If you don't do so, you may end up voiding your insurance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no arcing problem provided you are not mixing mains and logic in the one switch or switch wall-box.

Note that contact resistance could be a problem as the low voltages involved won't be able to break down any contamination on the switch contacts. Gold plating is often used on quality signal switch contacts rather than plain brass in mains switches.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok, will work. But you have to remember that it doesn't switch momentarily, it take few miliseconds of bouncing until it's on or off. So you may want to add a filter.